# cannot convert system.data.datarow to dataset.row

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm stuck at a line of code where im trying to save a row:

```
int _id = Convert.ToInt32(grdUnapprovedArticles.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Value);
        ArticlesBLL _ArticlesBLL = new ArticlesBLL();
        ArticlesDataSet.ArticlesRow _article = _ArticlesBLL.GetDataByArticleID(_id).Rows[0];
```

The problem is in line 3 and it says that I cannot convert system.data.datarow to articlesdataset.datarow.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: What is `ArticlesBLL.GetDataByArticleID()`? What does it return?

Comment: ArticlesBLL is a class file where i have a function GetDataByArticleID where it returns articles based on ID

Comment: returns the article with the selected id (Article name , contenct etxc)

Comment: What _type_ does it return?

Comment: i dont get it.. it returns the whole row every field has different type

Comment: You need to learn about functions and types.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx Show us the function declaration.

Comment: Try a cast...ArticlesDataSet.ArticlesRow _article = (ArticlesDataSet.ArticlesRow)_ArticlesBLL.GetDataByArticleID(_id).Rows[0];